# Is this cast of void pointer valid code or vile code?

Tags: c, casting, undefined-behavior

Is this valid/proper code, or does it violate standards -- possibly invoking undefined behavior (UB)?

--> Specifically, the cast of `void *` to `char **` in `foo()`.  <--

It does [work](https://godbolt.org/z/Kcxb9jP6n), but we know that 'working' isn't good enough.

*And any other errors*, please rip it up and post corrected code if you like, please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

void foo(void *vp)
{
    char **dp = (char **)vp;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", dp[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **dp;
    int i;

    dp = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        dp[i]= malloc(20);
        sprintf(dp[i],"Now: %d\n",i);
    }
    foo(dp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Now: 0
Now: 1
Now: 2
Now: 3
Now: 4
```

I tried `foo(void **vp)` which *seems right to me* but does not compile.  Conversely, `foo(void *vp)` seems wrong(?) but compiles and works.  I've not been concerned with trivialities like this until now, as I am wanting to take my C to the next level.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? You're casting to the type of the original pointer, what could be wrong with that?

Comment: Why are you using a `void *` argument in the first place?  Why aren't you using `char **`?

Comment: @JohnBode This is probably a simplification of the real need, which could be something generic like `qsort()`.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that `void*` is intended to allow. If you can't cast back to the original type, what use would it be?

Comment: @Barmar -- it just seems wrong to cast *any* single pointer to a double pointer, but this is why I'm here, to get past my unknowing.

Comment: @JohnBode -- yes, it's like Barmar said -- this is a simple version of a larger potential application of the principle, and for knowing and not guessing.  I've coded in a vacuum my whole life and sometimes it shows.

Comment: A void pointer `void*` can point to anything, including other pointers of any type  OTOH `void**` can only point at a `void*`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: Re “A void pointer `void*` can point to anything”: The C standard does not define converting pointers to functions to `void *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `void *` is essentially a generic pointer type.  Any object pointer type, regardless of how many "levels" that pointer is, may be converted to a `void *` and back without a cast.

Because of this, the conversion from `void *` to `char **` is not only safe but the cast is unnecessary.

Trying to use `void **` doesn't work because the special treatment given to `void *` doesn't carry over to a `void **`.  A `void **` is a specific type: a pointer to a `void *`.

Comment: Oh -- *without a cast* -- this didn't occur to me, lol.   But yes, [the compiler does not complain at all](https://godbolt.org/z/Tb6f3MG63) -- thank you.  Well, this is very complete and with a note about why void ** is a no-go... thanks again

Comment: Well, this answers my question in full, and community clearly likes it too -- so congrats and thank you!